# Calling router from backbonejs and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, pushstate

I have an web app. Basically its a single page application. The initial page is a flat html file called index.html, with a single script declaration pointing to require.js. From there I use backbonejs to handle the client side logic. The index.html is being served by nodejs.

My issue is that, any action within the page, for example, i click on a link, the backbone router is called. Which is the behavior I want being a single page application.

For example: *www.testserver.com* then i click on a link which shows a modal screen for registration *www.testserver.com/register*, via backbone router with **push state on**

The issue arrises when, instead of accessing a certain link within the app, i open the url straight in browser. For example I paste, *www.testserver.com/register*, in the browser. The request is then sent to my node router. I am assuming this is the correct behavior, since the page doesnt exist yet, meaning the backbone router doesnt exist as well.

I was wondering, on what the correct work around for this is. What am i supposed to do, when i access this link? How do i pass the correct behavior back to my backbone application.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can't you just return your index.html from your server and your Backbone router will handle the path on the client side?

Answer (score 2):

The server should return always the index.html page. When you start the router in your Backbone than, the router handle the navigation and call the function you defined for the actual route.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need to do any SEO type stuff such that each unique URL loads its own metadata, just always serve the same index.html as stated. However if you want to have different static head content based on the URL, you should do that within node based on the path (e.g. keep an array of metadata for each route that you slip into a slightly-more-dynamic initial view template, based on your existing flat index.html)